# Magento2 - Get image url in model/helper

Tags: magento2, module, image, helper

I have a helper class Email under `vendor/module/model/helper/Email.php`

I have to access a image in the `module_path/view/frontend/web/images`

I can't use `$this->getViewFileUrl('vendor_module::images/image.jpg');` or `$block->getViewFileUrl('vendor_module::images/image.jpg');`

How can I call the image in my helper class?

Helper file

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

/**
 * Class Email
 * @package Vendor\Module\Model\Helper
 */
class Email
{
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    )
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }
    /**
     * @param array $params
     */
    public function sendBasicmoduleFormMails(array $params)
    {
        $params = array('_secure' => $this->request->isSecure());
        $image = $this->assetRepo->getUrlWithParams('Vendor_Module::images/image.jpg', $params);
        $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: <from_email>" . "\r\n" .

        $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
        $body = "Some email content with an {$image}";

        mail(some_email, 'a subject', $body, $headers);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get Image Path in your Helper or Controller, you need to use

```
use Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface; // for $this->result

protected $request;

public function __construct(
      Repository $assetRepo,
      RequestInterface $request,
)
{
      $this->assetRepo = $assetRepo;
      $this->request = $request;
}
```

in your file.
Once you add the repository and create object `assetRepo` & `result`, call image path with function,

```
$params = array('_secure' => $this->request->isSecure());
$this->assetRepo->getUrlWithParams('Vendor_Module::images/image.jpg', $params);
```

Refer to `vendor\magento\module-payment\Model\CcConfig.php::getViewFileUrl($fileId, array $params = [])` function

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i get the following error: `Undefined property: Vendor\Module\Model\Helper\Email::$request`

Comment: Please check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks for your update, but i get the following error `Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Vendor\Module\Model\Helper\Email::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http, none given` Many thanks for your help

Comment: can you please add your helper file?

Comment: Updated question

Comment: your Email Helper class should be like this  `class Email extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66887/discussion-between-abhishek-panchal-and-frank-groot).

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for getting image url in Helper:

```
protected $assetRepo;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->assetRepo = $assetRepo;
    ...
}
```

Now, you can get image URL by:

```
echo $this->assetRepo->getUrl("Vendor_Module::images/img.jpg");
```